# Как из строки (string) сделать enum в java

Tags: java, enum

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть описание цветов в enum, при замене string данные enum клипс начинает ругаться. Я нагною что можно заменить подогнать в ручную, но есть способ как сделать из переменной string enum. Подскажите ПЛЗ.

Answer (score 3):

```
this.colour = Colour.valueOf(colour);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не очень понятно в какую часть это вставить.

Comment: В конструктор вставить, вместо this.color = color